# Proof of uniform continuity of a rational function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f\colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)= \dfrac{4x}{1+x}$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: What does the definition of uniformly continuous tell you? Surely the definition suggests an approach.

Comment: It kinda depends on the class and chapter. You can prove it by differentiating, by epsilon-delta, by rational functions properties and probably some other ways I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: since $\;f(x)=4-\frac4{1+x}\;$

$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|-\frac4{1+x}+\frac4{1+y}\right|=4\left|\frac{x-y}{(1+x)(1+y)}\right|\le4|x-y|$$

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the MVT you can obtain Timbucs inequality also as follows: Due to the MVT there holds

$$|f(x)-f(y)|= | f'(\xi)| = \left|\frac{4}{(1+\xi)^2}\right| |x-y|\leq 4 |x-y|$$

for some $\xi \in (x,y)\cup (y,x)$. Particularly, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[0,\infty)$.